# Override Core Data to-many property and return a filtered set

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I’ve got an `NSManagedObject` with a `childNodes` property in its model. Now I want to override the `childNodes` property and return a filtered version of it, but I keep getting crashes. Here’s what I’ve got in my `NSMO` subclass:

```
- (NSOrderedSet *)childNodes {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@“childNodes”];
    NSMutableOrderedSet *result = [self primitiveChildNodes];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"childNodes”];

    NSArray *filteredResult = [[result array] myCustomArrayFilteringMethod]; // let’s say this returns the first half of the array, as a contrived example

    return [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:filteredResults];
}
```

This works alright sometimes, but I’m finding crashes like: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSOrderedSet objectsAtIndexes:]: index 24 in index set beyond bounds [0 .. 19]’` and I’m not sure why. Call stack seems to be related to mutating a collection, but I’m mutating a copy so I’m not sure what’s happening:

```
0   CoreFoundation         __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib        objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation         -[NSOrderedSet objectsAtIndexes:] + 952
3   Foundation             NSKeyValueWillChangeByOrderedToManyMutation + 568
4   Foundation             NSKeyValueWillChange + 383
5   Foundation             -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:] + 557
6   CoreData               -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _excludeObject:fromPropertyWithKey:andIndex:] + 526
7   CoreData               -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _maintainInverseRelationship:forProperty:oldDestination:newDestination:] + 254
8   CoreData               -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _didChangeValue:forRelationship:named:withInverse:] + 567
9   Foundation             NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 347
10  Foundation             NSKeyValueDidChange + 466
11  Foundation             -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 118
12  CoreData               -[NSManagedObject didChangeValueForKey:] + 135
13  CoreData               -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _updateFromRefreshSnapshot:includingTransients:] + 758
14  CoreData               -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _copyChildObject:toParentObject:fromChildContext:] + 567
15  CoreData               -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentProcessSaveRequest:inContext:error:] + 1103
16  CoreData               __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 364
17  CoreData               internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 84
18  libdispatch.dylib      _dispatch_client_callout + 8
19  libdispatch.dylib      _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 284
20  libdispatch.dylib      _dispatch_client_callout + 8
21  libdispatch.dylib      _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
22  CoreFoundation         __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
23  CoreFoundation         __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
24  CoreFoundation         CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
25  GraphicsServices       GSEventRunModal + 161
26  UIKit                  UIApplicationMain + 171
27  My app                 main + 111
28  libdyld.dylib
```

Any suggestions? I can’t quite figure this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't. Add a different method which returns a filtered copy of the original relationship. Also, for the implementation just iterate the collection and add the items you want to keep to an entirely new collection, don't copy and filter.

The crash is because the array you're filtering is actually backed by the datastore, so as you filter it it's changing the contents you're iterating with the filter, and it's screwing up the original relationship.